# EzPublish 5 friendly URL's won't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ezpublish

i have set up a local EzPUblish 5 installation, and it seems to work, with one exception: friendly URLs.

When I go to http://arabia.local/index.php/Frontpage, it works, but if I go to http://arabia.local/Frontpage, it tells me 404 not found.

I did some research already; I copied the .htaccess_root to .htaccess, I set the ForceVirtualHost=true in site.ini, I checked in my httpd.conf that AllowOverride All is set - I am running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files and settings you mentioned mostly concern eZ Publish's legacy part and will most likely have no effect on the frontend.

From what you're describing, the first thought that came to me was that the VHost configuration might be not complete. Please compare your configuration with the one eZ Systems officially provides: [Virtual host setup](https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP/Virtual+host+setup) and [.htaccess example](https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP/htaccess+example).

Are you perhaps missing the following line?

```
RewriteRule .* index\.php
```

Please also keep in mind that your webserver's root must point to the "web" directory, and if you are not using a VHost based configuration, the .htaccess file must reside in the "web" directory (but to be honest, I haven't seen a non-VHost based setup yet, so I'm not sure about the .htaccess method.

Nonetheless there should be no need to change anything in the "ezpublish_legacy" directory, especially not for an initial setup.

Comment: for some reason, putting it in the "web" directory did the trick. And yes, I am using vhosts, so that's kinda weird. But well, it works now, thanks!